# JupyterHub to execute on all CPUs

Tags: python, server, virtual-machine, jupyterhub

I have JupyterHub installed on an Ubuntu Server over VM Ware virtualization.

I have 30 CPUs and 128GB of ram.

When I run some code in python in JupterHub it seems to only utilize one of the CPUs.

Is there anything I can do to make it distribute the work and hence bring down the total execution time of my scripts?

[image: How the machine looks while running]

Comment: Seems like your Jupyterhub installation might have a limit set on cpu. Please check the documentation on configuring user resources [here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-resources.html). Hope this helps!